# I somehow screwed this up badly (Python PIP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I was cleaning out my laptop and somehow screwed up my Python installation. Now I'm getting an error that I can't even find the answer to in Google (I usually copy and paste the error msg as a Google search and it usually leads me to an answer on here or other sites). This is the error msg verbatim: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install Flask': The system cannot find the file specified.
I just reinstalled Python 3.10 via the installer from the Python site (so as not to screw up with Linux install since it likes to auto install 2.7 for some reason)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as always

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Where did you install Python 3.10?  What were you running when you encountered that error?   Do you have either c:\python310\python.exe or c:\python310\Scripts\pip.exe?

Comment: Hi brogrammer, it's hard to figure out what's going on in your current question. Are you using Linux or Windows (the error suggests Windows `C:\ ` )? You mentioned an error but we don't know what you're trying to do? Did you type `python` in your command line? Are you running a script?

I'd also recommend glancing over [this](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/) to organize your question properly. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: @ewong I actually installed straight to PATH according to the installer recommendations as my last attempt to fix this, was to download straight from python.org

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "installed straight to PATH"

Comment: @Spidey I'm using windows and I'm actually trying to run a Flask project I've already been working on. Everything was working fine until last night i went cleaning out my laptop. I noticed I had like 3 versions of Python installed, so I decided to delete the older ones and keep 3.10. However, I somehow screwed that up and so i decided to try through Linux, then via the actual installer from python.org. I am trying to reinstall flask and all the modules I need, but that's the error thrown at me every time

Comment: @ewong during installation through the python.org installer, it asks if you want to install to PATH. I checked yes, as I already know that's the preferable setup config

Comment: PATH is  not the preferable setup config if you have multiple Python installations, because the earliest one in the path wins.  You'll also see a default option for the [Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).  Just run "py" to get the latest python installed or "py -3.8" (for example) to run an older version.

Comment: Mark Tolonen alluded to what is probably your main problem. You probably have/had Flask installed for a version of python you no longer use or which is no longer used due to your PATH setup. I usually prefer to have a `virtualenv` for each project to avoid confusions such as these.

Comment: @Spidey I think that's probably my best bet. I'm still a big noob to this and I'm just trying to get better. y'alls advice has been very helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.